# Galois group of $x^{8}+16$

Tags: galois-theory

I was trying to do that problem. I first found that the roots of the polynomial are $e^{\frac{k\pi i}{8}}\sqrt{2}$ with $k=1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15$. Then, I say that if $\sigma$ is an element of the Galois group then $\sigma(e^{\frac{\pi i}{8}}\sqrt{2})=e^{\frac{k\pi i}{8}}\sqrt{2}$ for another root. Then I claim that this will uniquely determine $\sigma$ since $\sigma(e^{\frac{(2m+1)\pi i}{8}}\sqrt{2})=\frac{1}{2^m}\sigma((e^{\frac{\pi i}{8}}\sqrt{2})^{2m+1})$, and since we can send it to any other root then we get that the Galois group has $8$ elements. So I think since we are mapping $1$ into an odd number defined modulo $16$ then would the galois group be isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z})^\times$?

Comment: A good start. But how do know that there are exactly 8 automorphisms?

Comment: Or in other words: Do you know the degree of the splitting field? If you know that the polynomial is irreducible, and that the splitting field is of degree 8, then your calculations kick in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am slightly expanding on your own work. Consider, as you did,
$$
\alpha = \sqrt{2} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}} + i \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}\right)
= \sqrt{2} \cdot  (\cos(\pi/8) + i \sin(\pi/8)).
$$
We have $\alpha^{8} = -16$, and thus $\alpha$ is a root of $f = x^8 + 16$. Note that $$\eta = \cos(\pi/8) + i \sin(\pi/8)$$ is a primitive $16$-th root of unity, and that $$\sqrt{2} = (\eta + \eta^{-1})^2 - 2 = \eta^2 + \eta^{-2} \in \mathbf{Q}[\eta^2].$$

Moreover,
$\dfrac{\alpha^2}{2} = \eta^{2}$, so $\eta^2 \in \mathbf{Q}[ \alpha ]$. It follows
$$
\mathbf{Q}[ \sqrt{2} ] \subseteq \mathbf{Q}[ \eta^2 ] \subseteq \mathbf{Q}[\alpha] \subseteq \mathbf{Q}[ \eta ].
$$
Since $\alpha/\sqrt{2} = \eta$, it follows $\mathbf{Q}[\alpha] = \mathbf{Q}[ \eta ]$. In particular, $\mathbf{Q}[\alpha]$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbf{Q}$.

Now it is well-known that $\lvert \mathbf{Q}[ \eta ] : \mathbf{Q} \rvert = \varphi(16) = 8$, so that $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbf{Q}$, and the Galois group is isomorphic to the group of units of $\mathbf{Z}_{16}$, and it is thus isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}_{4} \times \mathbf{Z}_{2}$.